# trouble w np.where on specific complex data structure created from random numbers

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I was attempting to use `np.where()` to return the index of elements in a  complex data structure.  This was part of a learning experiment.

But `np.where()` did not work consistently during my tests.  Tests were conducted in iPython and behaved the same on Python 2.7 and 3.6.

The original data structure:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m3d=np.random.rand(3,4,5)
n3d=m3d.reshape(4,3,5)
o3d=np.random.rand(2,3,4,5)
simp1=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
simp2=np.array([[10,9,8,7,6]])
simp3=[11,12,13]
# a dictionary
dfrm1 = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
        'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
        'population': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9]}
# convert dictionary to DataFrame
dfrm1 = pd.DataFrame(dfrm1)

crazyList = [simp1, m3d, simp2, n3d, simp3, dfrm1, o3d]
trueSimp1=np.array([10,9,8,7,6])
crazyList.append(trueSimp1)
crazyList2 = list(crazyList)
```

Since two of the nested sub-structures are populated with randomly generated numbers, the value to use in `np.where()` has to be copied and pasted from the output of the data structure cell into the code in the test cell when testing `np.where()`

The weird thing is that some attempts to use `np.where()` to locate an index worked fine while others did not.

The above code generated a data structure for `crazyList2` that included the following (just showing the first part used in this example):

```
[[[1,2,3,4,5]],
 [[[ 0.49555906  0.14471098  0.69386405  0.80504314  0.35316356]
  [ 0.40202873  0.40388709  0.67211181  0.52745945  0.49144579]
  [ 0.83240025  0.8187909   0.64860856  0.82538625  0.52107398]
  [ 0.74900576  0.98173857  0.83579314  0.24578775  0.05530318]]

 [[ 0.74250275  0.31464713  0.99314855  0.47654982  0.08117959]
  [ 0.11474039  0.16351823  0.24030983  0.1734985   0.10746642]
  [ 0.45627385  0.04654085  0.02521171  0.04290553  0.44018312]
  [ 0.25114034  0.21058291  0.83786011  0.50925183  0.94918242]]

 [[ 0.48894954  0.33250801  0.42154765  0.05738124  0.81262202]
  [ 0.73752384  0.98451401  0.0684456   0.17910599  0.00412605]
  [ 0.06446881  0.40695243  0.51251566  0.39912532  0.01384556]
  [ 0.84967808  0.28460418  0.62816424  0.08959918  0.13076973]]],
  # data structure continues with more sub elements not used in this test ...
```

An attempt to use `np.where()` to find out an index on the first sub-element is successful:

test code:

```
print(crazyList[0])
np.where(crazyList[0]==2)
```

reports the index as:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]]
(array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

But an attempt to run the same test on the more complex structure in the second element fails.  It produces empty output.

Test code:

```
print(np.where(crazyList2[1]==0.83579314))
```

Output:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

The number used in the above test was copied from the output of printing the data structure without re-running it, so we know we are dealing with a number that exists in the sub-element.  Further, as suggested in comments, using a test with `np.isclose()` instead of `==` works, but is not as specific as we'd like.  You can modify the test value by pushing its last digit up or down by 1 and the `np.isclose()` test will still work even though the changed number does not exist in the data structure.

Why did this second attempt to use `np.where()` fail while the first one succeeded?

Comment: You are running into floating pt issues. Use `np.isclose` for such cases instead of `==`.

Comment: The key to understanding funny `where` results is to understand the condition test.  All `where` does is find the `True` elements in `A == B`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Did a bit more investigating and looked into what you wrote.  First comment:  `np.isclose` seems to fix the problem on the surface.  But if you need an exact match, then the loss of precision is an issue.  I tested two more numbers not found in the array by just increasing or decreasing the last digit by 1 and they returned the same index results.  Second comment - I get that it is doing a True/False test.  What I don't get is why my first one works and my second one does not. I did a simple floating point test outside my crazyList and it seemed to work.

Comment: This test also works whereas my example above behaves as shown:  `np.where(np.array([[0.98822145, 0.09783841, 0.07314108, 0.54074233, 0.3720003]])==0.07314108)`

Comment: Question modified to better reflect the nature of the problem just now.  Testing has revealed a pattern in the symptoms that will get posted as an answer as well in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further testing corroborates the "floating point" rounding error explanation posted in comments to this question.  The purpose of this post is to explain the conditions under which the problem occurs and how to work around these conditions.

This testing may prove useful in that regard:

re-create this object:

```
import numpy as np
m3d=np.random.rand(3,4,5)
```

Now access one of the numbers within the object, but formatting the output in all the different ways shown here:

```
print(m3d[0][1][3])
print("{0:.17f}".format(m3d[0][1][3]))
print("{0:.20f}".format(m3d[0][1][3]))
print("{0:.25f}".format(m3d[0][1][3]))
print("{0:.30f}".format(m3d[0][1][3]))
```

Since numbers were randomly generated, you will get output that is different.  When I did it, my output was this:

```
0.640593901718
0.64059390171803487
0.64059390171803487490
0.6405939017180348749036511
0.640593901718034874903651143541
```

If enough decimal places are not used, the `T/F` condition returns `False` even if it matches on all digits up to that point.  But it should be noted that if too many decimal places are used, `np.where()` will not support that level of precision and will behave more like `np.isclose()` in that specific scenario.

I first realized to test with 17 decimal places after I output the results of `m3d[0][1][3]` in its own iPython cell and saw it was coming back with more decimal places than when viewed by printing the whole object: `print(md3)`.

Further testing suggests that precision is only reliable out to 16 decimal places.  With 17, if two numbers are identical up to the first 16 digits after the decimal point, they will be treated the same.

In the real world, if you are using `np.where()`, you should know exactly what number you are looking for, or should be satisfied with `np.isclose()` if the exact number is not known.

The scenario that came up in the original post was due more to the nature of the test and the author's not realizing how floating point numbers get rounded/displayed, than due to a set of conditions that might come up in the real world to cause problems with code when using `np.where().`